# How can I detect if a store has 'Advanced Shopify' through the API

Tags: shopify

Shopify has various levels of service that has include various features.

https://www.shopify.com/pricing

I only want to show features of my Shopify app, to customers that have those features.

Is there a way to detect, via the Shopify API, what version of Shopify my customers have?

For example I want to know if someone connecting to my app with their Shopify store, has 'Advanced Shopify' so I can show them specific features.

I have looked through the Shopify APIs a lot, https://help.shopify.com/api/reference, and googled it extensively, haven't seen anything.

Comment: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/enumeration-of-plan_name-from-get-admin-shop-json-352847 - this is a crowdsourced list of the different types of plan available since Shopify doesn't provide them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get store type information by accessing `/admin/shop.json` of the store using api.
Check the **"plan_name"** attribute of the json.

Refer [this](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/shop) for more.